# How can I parse the hierarchy of a XamPivotGrid?

Tags: c#, wpf, infragistics, attachedbehaviors

I'm working on writing an attached behavior to duplicate column and row expansion across two `XamPivotGrid`s which have different data sources.

The behavior works, but at any hierarchy level other than the outermost, all rows expand simultaneously. I'd like to filter my query for header rows to only get a header with the same parent. Herein lies the problem:

My initial pivot grid has four measures, one row, and one column. Only one measure is selected by default. To create a hierarchy, I (using the `XamPivotDataSelector` control) drag the column to also act as a row, which makes the measure act as the column. While this appears to be a hierarchy on the pivot grid, in actuality one is still one of the grid's RowHeaders and the other a ColumnHeader - they share no relationship I can access.

After searching online, I haven't found any information on how I might go about accessing whatever it is that can be used to identify a particular header. I realize that this question may require sufficiently deep knowledge of the `XamPivotGrid` control that I may never get an answer, so I will continue poring over the grid in the hopes that I may be able to answer this question myself.

Thank you for your time.

**UPDATE:**
I have found that the columns do indeed become rows rather than columns, so at least that much makes more sense, but they are simply in a list, rather than being hierarchically arranged.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the row/column structure when there's a hierarchy does in fact simulate a tree. Because I don't have experience converting a list to a tree, and because the two grids I deal with are always going to have the same rows and columns, I was able to do something different.

Essentially, `grid.GridLayout.RowHeaderCells` items are guaranteed to have the same index in all grids. I don't have to deal with trees, just an index.

**EDIT:**

In fact, this solution turned out to be unhelpful in my case, because while rows and columns remain the same, they may be hidden. Instead, I found i was able to use `PivotHeaderCell.Member.Tuple.ToString()` to reliably generate the 'path' I was searching for in my question, so everything is now better.